# setting cross-subdomain cookies accessible to a sub-subdomain?

Tags: cookies, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I've set a cookie with domain of `.example.com`. It is available for every first-level subdomain on my site, as it should be.

It is not, however, available on *n*th level subdomains, i.e. `sub.subdomain.example.com` and `too.many.subdomains.subdomain.example.com` don't see the cross-subdomain cookie while `subdomain.example.com` does. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The client seems not to follow the rules specified in the rfc.
IE fails when there's an underscore in the domain name.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3